# AngularJS wait submit the Form (ng-submit)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

I have one Form, In this I submit this form when it loads.

I want that when this page is load it waits for some number of seconds then it submit this form.
I don't want to submit this form by using any button, It should be Auto Submit form. Is it possible?

My html page code is given below

```
<form name="main" ng-submit="submitForm(main_1)">
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtFirstname" name="txtFirstname" ng-model="verifyData.firstName" /></td>
            <td>Middle Initial :</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtMiddlename" name="txtMiddlename" ng-model="verifyData.middleInitial" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="images/loader.gif" id="loading-image" ng-if="showLoader">
    <div id="load1" ng-if="showLoader"></div>
</form>
```

My controller code is given below

```
angular.module(appConfig.appName)
    .controller('appController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$window', 'globalService', 'dataServices', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $window, globalService, dataServices) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            window.history.forward();
        });

        $scope.showLoader = false;
        var firstName = document.getElementById('txtFirstname');
        if (firstName != null) {
            var lastName = document.getElementById('txtLastname');
        }

        $scope.submitForm = function () {
            $scope.showLoader = true;
            dataServices.verifyData($scope.verifyData).then(function (response) {
                $state.go(response.redirectURL);
            }, function (res) {
                $rootScope.serviceErrorMsg = res.error;
                $state.go(res.redirectURL);
            });
        }

        if ($scope.verifyData) {
            $scope.submitForm();
        }
    }])
]);
```

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: use $timeout method by giving specified intervals to wait and call the submitform method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the timeout service for Angular

```
$timeout(function () {
        $scope.submitForm();
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout method to call automatically submit for after specific interval

```
$timeout( function(){
        // call submitform method
    }, 5000 );
```

Comment: Where I have to use this, inside the controller?

Comment: But it comes to the controller after submitting the form, Is it correct?

Comment: keep the timeout call at the end in your controller. So nothing get change even after submitting and controller getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout to submit the form after 2 sec after controller initialization:
`$timeout($scope.submitForm, 2000)`

Comment: Can you please explain where I have to write this code, Inside the controller?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Place this inside your controller. And don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use $timeout or if you want do something else when this something end you submit, you can use otherwise Promises.

`$timeout( function(){
        // code
    }, 3000 );`

or

`Some_Function().then(function(){
  //YourCode
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
Write the code in $timeout (Note :- Just Insert $timeout as a dependency otherwise it will give error)
```

Like this
.controller('appController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$window', 'globalService', 'dataServices', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $window, globalService, dataServices, $timeout)

```
For example :- 
$scope.submitForm = function () {
            $scope.showLoader = true;
            dataServices.verifyData($scope.verifyData).then(function (response) {
                $state.go(response.redirectURL);
            }, function (res) {
                $rootScope.serviceErrorMsg = res.error;
                $state.go(res.redirectURL);
            });
        }
$timeout(function(){
 $scope.submitForm();
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple to use method would be to do this 

**In your View (HTML)- disable the submit button**
`<button ng-readonly="button_readonly" ng-disabled="button_disabled" name="Submit">SUBMIT</button>`

**In the controller, these values are originally set to false**
`$scope.button_readonly = false;`
`$scope.button_disabled = false;`

because of angular data binding. you can then do your logic.
if logic returns successfully (whether ajax, or input validation etc, then you can set
the above to true

on success:

**Set to true**
`$scope.button_readonly = true;`
`$scope.button_disabled = true;`

at this point: your button is now clickable. thus, it is ready to be pushed (submit) to php

**In php** 
`if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){`
 `//do your thing`
`}`

To answer your question. Since you don't want to use the button
add the hidden attribute to the button. Then periodically check to see if
the values have changed. when they do, add the submit logic. ie. if button_readonly = true; submit